# luapstricks error

Tags: errors, luatex, pstricks, luapstricks

Consider the following non-MWE:

```
\documentclass[
  a4paper,
  landscape,
  12pt
]{article}

\usepackage[margin = 2.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[version = 4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\def\runding{0.25}
\def\mlr{-0.75}
\newcommand*\navn[1]{\Huge\textbf{#1}}
\newcommand*\led[1]{\large\textbf{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{pspicture}(24.4,16)
  % Start.
  \psframe[framearc = \runding](6,14)(10.8,16)
  \rput(8.4,15){\navn{Atomer}}
  % Først mellemstykke.
  \psline(7.6,14)(3,9)
  \rput*(5.3,11.5){\led{Et enkelt}}
  \psline(9.2,14)(14,9)
  \rput*(11.6,11.5){\led{Flere sammen}}
  % Anden række.
  \psframe[framearc = \runding](0,7)(6,9)
  \rput(3,8){%
    \shortstack[c]{%
      \navn{Grundstof}\strut\\[\mlr ex]
      (f.eks. \ce{Fe} eller \ce{Mg})\strut
    }%
  }
  \psframe[framearc = \runding](11,7)(17,9)
  \rput(14,7.9){\navn{Molekyle}}
  % Andet mellemstykke.
  \psline(12.9,7)(8.6,2)
  \rput*(10.75,4.5){\led{Samme slags}}
  \psline(15.1,7)(19.4,2)
  \rput*(17.25,4.5){\led{Forskellige slags}}
  % Tredje række.
  \psframe[framearc = \runding](5.6,0)(11.6,2)
  \rput(8.6,1){%
    \shortstack[c]{%
      \navn{Grundstof}\strut\\[\mlr ex]
      (f.eks. \ce{H2} eller \ce{O2})\strut
    }%
  }
  \psframe[framearc = \runding](14.4,0)(24.4,2)
  \rput(19.4,1){%
    \shortstack[c]{%
      \navn{Kemisk forbindelse}\strut\\[\mlr ex]
      (f.eks. \ce{H2O} eller \ce{CO2})\strut
    }%
  }
\end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

When I compile using `lualatex`, I get the following error:

```
luapstricks.lua:794: Unknown name "tx@Dict"
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    ...2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luapstricks/luapstricks.lua:4178: in function 
<...2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luapstricks/luapstricks.lua:4153>
    [C]: in function 'vf.node'
    ...2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luapstricks/luapstricks.lua:4146: in function 
<...2022/texmf-dist/tex/lualatex/luapstricks/luapstricks.lua:4137>.
<argument> ...not:N \tex_shipout:D \box_use:N \l_shipout_box 
                                                  \__shipout_drop_firstpage_...

l.63 \end{document}
```

However, when I compile using `latex` --> `dvips` --> `ps2pdf -dALLOWPSTRANSPARENCY` everything is fine.

I have a feeling this might be do to a bug in [`luapstricks`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/luapstricks) (although I'm not sure) but how do I fix it?

Comment: move the figure to page 2.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you. I would like to have a document spanning only a single page; is that possible?

Comment: Then why do you use a figure if you don't want to float anything?

Comment: Excellent point. I have no good reason; I simply forgot. Thank you very much!

Comment: Still seems to be a bug though? Is there a reason why you can't use pstricks inside a (unnecessary) float on the first page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
    \begin{pspicture}(24.4,16)
       \pstVerb{(pstricks.pro) run}
        % Start.
```

I must investigate to see why `tx@Dict` is missing.

Comment: Will be fixed by tomorrows update of TeXLive and MiKTeX for pstricks-base and pstricks-lua.